# I am getting an error when reversing an array by iterating it till half

Tags: java

I have tried to reverse an array by running it till half so that if it has odd number of element then middle one is left out as it is not needed to be swapped and if it's even then every element will be swapped but I don't know where I'm wrong.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // write your code here
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scn.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[x];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = scn.nextInt();
        }
        int temp = x;
        for(int i = 0  ; i < temp / 2 ;i++)
        {
            int temp1 = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[x - 1];
            arr[x - 1] = temp1;
            x--;
        }
        for(int z=0;z<arr.length;z++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[z]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the error - as well as the input you're running with.

Comment: Since you are changing `x` in each loop, `x/2` gets smaller and smaller. You shouldn't touch `x`, or you should use `arr.length/2`.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to *show* that `x/2` should be cast as an integer.  Although Java will do this implicitly in this case, I like clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close in your attempt.  See the following with changes.

```
       for(int i = 0  ; i < temp / 2 ;i++)
        {
            int temp1 = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[x - 1]; // should be arr[x - i - 1]
            arr[x - 1] = temp1;  // should be arr[x - i - 1]
            x--; // delete this line
        }
```